# Ionic 2 Native Map overlapping side menu

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins, native

Created Ionic 2 Native map following Josh Morony tutorial:

http://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-native-google-maps-into-an-ionic-2-application/ .

Everything works well. Here's the problem:

My view have a side menu, when I click on side menu, it toggles appear, but the options inside are unclickable. When I double click the menu option in emulator, the map zoomed in. The map has overlapped my side menu, is there any solution for this emergency?

Thank you.

Comment: can you show some code? where have you added the menu?

Comment: The menu is added when I create "ionic start", I believe under the map that's why menu is not accessible. I can still see the menu, but unable to click. I don't know how to show the codes, but basically the same with what I posted above from Josh Morony.

Comment: You can add the html part in the question and use `` to wrap the code..

Comment: The tutorial doesnt really have the menu

Comment: Just to let you know...you're not crazy. I'm seeing the exact same behavior when using the native google maps plugin with a side menu.

Answer (score 6):

it is expected behaviour according to the plugin documentation, what you need to do is when sidebar is opened - map.setClickable(false), then when it closes turn back the clickable to true.

For example, let's presume that the menu is on the main component, so u do something like this in the template (app.html):

```
<ion-menu #sidebar [content]="content" (ionOpen)="onMenuOpen($event)" (ionClose)="onMenuClose($event)">
```

in app.ts or however it is called for you

```
    onMenuOpen(event) {
    this.events.publish('sidebar:open');
}

onMenuClose(event) {
    this.events.publish('sidebar:close');
}
```

then on the map component u attached a listener when the map is ready:

```
            map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(() => {

            this.events.subscribe('sidebar:open', () => {
                map.setClickable(false);
            });

            this.events.subscribe('sidebar:close', () => {
                map.setClickable(true)
            });
```

and probably unsubscribe when the page is closed:

```
    ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.events.unsubscribe('sidebar:open');
    this.events.unsubscribe('sibebar:close');
}
```

do not forget to

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
```

and inject the events in each component constuctor

```
constructor(
    private events: Events
) {
```

hope that helps.

Comment: smooth . better than previous

Answer (score 4):

`<ion-menu type="push" [content]="content">` works good for me

Comment: but this gives a laggy experience. although it shifts the map

Answer (score 3):

In [Ionic Framework 2](https://ionicframework.com/) you could force the [menu type](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/Menu/#usage) to quickly overcome this problem.

```
<ion-menu [content]="mycontent" type="push">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <p>some menu content, could be list items</p>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

or overwrite the [config](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/) variable **menuType** in your @**NgModule**

```
@NgModule({
  ...
    imports: [
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
    menuType: 'push',
    }, {}
  )],
...
})
```

*I'm still looking for a fix, will update when found.*

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide a solution for you, but Josh did a nice write-up on some of the issues you can expect with using the Cordova maps plugin, including the exact scenario we're both running into:

https://www.joshmorony.com/google-maps-in-ionic-2-native-or-web/

In short, since we're using Ionic 2 it might be best to simply go with the javascript SDK instead of the native plugin. I suspect that'll play much nicer with Ionic in general.